# DNS may be messed up on new GKE clusters

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I've spent many hours over the past few days trying to understand why one of my pods can't reach a mysql service running in the cluster. I can provide service configs if necessary, but my debugging effort led me to check DNS using [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/).

So from within a busybox pod running in my cluster, I tried the following command:

```
nslookup kubernetes.default
```

And got the following:

```
/ # nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:     10.7.240.10
Address:    10.7.240.10:53

** server can't find kubernetes.default: NXDOMAIN

*** Can't find kubernetes.default: No answer
```

Kube-dns is running

```
$ kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns

NAME                        READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-dns-5dcfcbf5fb-jgcxj   4/4       Running   0          20h
kube-dns-5dcfcbf5fb-t4wds   4/4       Running   0          20h
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. I would appreciate any help debugging or any documentation that might help.

Comment: The DNS issue may be because of busybox: https://github.com/docker-library/busybox/issues/48.

How does the mysql connectivity issue manifest exactly?

Comment: Using the `kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local` FQDN might help, but reading through the issue @Jukka linked, it seems like it might be specific to the Busybox tool set (which your application probably doesn't use directly).

Comment: @DavidMaze No luck with the other FQDN either: `*** Can't find kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local: No answer`. @Jukka I'm unable to connect to a mysql service from a web application running in the same cluster.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I was too hasty to debug DNS, and the busybox bug mentioned by @Jukka threw me off.

Following the steps in the [Debug Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/) docs, I was able to confirm that DNS is in fact working.

Will continue to investigate why my service is unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

are you running your mysql server in container under pod or running a CloudSql MySql instance?